# Change Value in Table after Each Year with help of Trigger

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012

I have table named `tbl_interest`. I am trying to make simple bank database. I want to write a trigger for interest that it will automatically add interest after one year and update details according to it. Interest rate will taken by another value or you can say it will be hard coded. This is schema of `tbl_interest`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_interest]
(
    [int_accno] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [int_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [int_oldbal] [float] NOT NULL,
    [int_interest] [float] NOT NULL,
    [int_totbal] [float] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Also apart from trigger, which way is best to do such operation?

Comment: This is **not** the job of a trigger. A trigger occurs whenever you *insert*, *update* or *delete* something from your table. What you want to do for this (calculating interest at the end of a year) is a **SQL Server Agent Job** that will be scheduled to run e.g. on Jan 1 at 3am in the morning (or something that makes sense to you) and that calculates and applies that interest to all your accounts

Comment: Ohk.. Thank you very much.. But can you tell me how to do it with SQL Server Agent?

Comment: Write a SQL statement to do your calculations & update, and then create a job in SQL Server Agent that gets executed as needed ...

Comment: Thanks marc for valuable input.. But Everytime "int_accno" and "int_interest: will be different.. How to pass different values according to it?